# How to define custom class and use it in helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to define a class and let many helpers use.

I can include `MvaasPortal` moude in fine,

Then I can new the object , but can not use any methods of the object,

It's so strange.

If I can not use the methods in the object, why I can new the object.
Ruby is so strange.

```
 @portal = Portal.new
```

There is no methods in `@portal` object

### mvaas_portal.rb

```
module MvaasPortal
    module InstanceMethods
      class Portal
        def initialize(server_url)
      ~~~~
        end
        def query_server(body_to_send={},session_id=nil)
      ~~~
        end
      end
    end

    def self.included(receiver)
        receiver.send :include, InstanceMethods
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using rails, you can use `ActiveSupport::Concern` : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html
If don't, take a look at the first example on the link.

Moreover, your namespace is a little bit weird and misses some context. Here is an example with a dummy method :

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module MvaasPortal
  include ActiveSupport::Concern

  def an_instance_method
    puts "Here!"
  end
end

class Portal
  include MvaasPortal
end

Portal.new.an_instance_method
=> "Here!"
```